# Is there anyway to login to twitchtv using android app and get the token?

Tags: android, twitch, twitch-api

I'm develop a application which have to connect Twitch.tv account with the application.I read the docs but cant find anything about sdk or something i can do to login and get the token or userId.Anyone ever did this before?

Comment: A Token is bound to the ApplicationID/ApplicationSecret. So you have to implement the authentication/autorization by your own.

Comment: thanks @Fusselchen,ya,there is no sdk or sthing of twitch but customer doesnt want to create their own login form -> solution is remove the login with twitch :rofl: